# nagios event handler restart remote service

Tags: centos, nagios

I Need to use the nagios event handler to restart ntp services.

My restart scripts

1: `cat /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/remote-restart`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ok"

/etc/init.d/ntpd restart

echo "done"
```

2: remote entry for `nrpe.cfg`

```
command[check_remote_restart]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/remote-restart
```

3: run the nagios command from server

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTNAME -p 5666 -c check_remote_restart
```

output:

```
ok

done
```

I am getting the output as in echo but still ntp service is not started.

Can somebody help me to find the soultion .

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running NRPE as root, you'll need to run that restart command through sudo.